# Is it possible to use samba share as blockchain data location?

Tags: monerod, ubuntu

I want to run a full node on my old laptop but the HDD is too small. I mounted a samba folder from my NAS but `monerod` is not synchronizing. I see a lot of errors. You can see them on [here](https://pastebin.com/XEuiPucc).

It works when I start `monerod` in my home dir, [here the logs](https://pastebin.com/vq7Nx9aH) .

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed.

My `fstab mount` output:

```
//192.168.1.105/disk/chain/ /home/skreitux/xmr cifs rw,_netdev,user=xxx,password=xxx,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0 0 0
```

And permissions:

```
skreitux@skreitux-laptop:~/xmr$ ls -la
total 4
drwxrwx--x+  5 skreitux skreitux    0 Jan 30 22:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 skreitux skreitux 4096 Jan 30 20:37 ..
drwxr-x--x+  3 skreitux skreitux    0 Jan 30 22:53 .bitmonero
drwxrwx--x+  3 skreitux skreitux    0 Jan 15 19:58 bitmonero_old`
```

Answer (score 2):

LMDB requires mmap to work, and searching the internet shows that Samba did not support mmap, but now does, at least on Linux. You might have to update your software, and configure it to have mmap support.